# In a one to many relationship, is it possible to do a query for parent based on if they have certain children without using count and group by?

Tags: sql

Say my the schema for these two tables is as follows:

```
owner
-----
pk owner_id int
owner_name text

possession
-----
pk possession_id int
possession_name text
fk owner_id int
```

Now, say the the records in these `possession` and `owner` tables are as follows:

```
owner
owner_id | owner_name
---------------------
1 | 'stephen'
2 | 'sarah'

possession
possession_id | possession_name | owner_id
------------------------------------------
1 | 'truck' | 1
2 | 'hammer | 1
3 | 'bottle' | 1
4 | 'truck' | 2
5 | 'island' | 2
```

In non-sql language: What is the query that could search for owners that have a truck *and* a hammer? And in sql language: is there a solution for this that does not use `count` + `group by`?

Comment: The general term for this is `relational division`. Hopefully you can see how it has similarities to arithmetic division.

Comment: Googling that now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
select owner_id
from possession
where possession_name in ('truck', 'hammer')
group by owner_id
having count(distinct possession_name) = 2;
```

If owner/possession is unique, then use `count(*)` instead of `count(distinct)`.

Comment: Would that still work well if `possession_name` was much more involved? This query is a very simplified version of what I'm doing, where in which the `possession_name` is more like, `clothing_category_name='suit', measurement_category_type='jacket', measurement_item_type='sleeve', item_measurement_value between $x and $y`. I'm using involved query that uses group by and count now and... it just feels like there must be a better way.

Comment: @Linum . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you ask.  This formulation doesn't care what the string representation of `possession_name` is.  However, if that is a concern, you should ask another query with appropriate information.

Answer (score 0):

use join and aggregate function

```
  select o.owner_name from possession p
     inner join 
    owner o on p.owner_id=o.owner_id 
    where possession_name in ('truck', 'hammer')
    group by  o.owner_name
    having count(distinct possession_name )>=2
```

or using sub-query

```
select * from owner o where o.owner_id  in (

    select t1.owner_id from
    (
    select owner_id from  possession p
    where possession_name in ('truck')
    ) t1
    inner join

    (
    select owner_id from  possession p
    where possession_name in ('truck')
    ) t2 on t1.owner_id =t2.owner_id 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `exists` whitch should be faster than doing join and group by:

```
select *
  from owner o
 where exists (select 1
                 from possession p1
                where p1.owner_id = o.owner_id
                  and p1.possession_name = 'hammer')
   and exists (select 1
                 from possession p2
                where p2.owner_id = o.owner_id
                  and p2.possession_name = 'truck')
```